# Пропадает отображение числа дней до знака Фанатик в мобильной версии для двузначных чисел

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, мобильная-версия

Пропадает отображение числа дней до знака Фанатик в мобильной версии для двузначных чисел.

Если прошло 9 дней:

> [image: Fanatic badge progress at 9 days]

10 дней:

> [image: Fanatic badge progress at ten days]

Подобную проблему наблюдаю только на SOru (включая мету). Вероятно, проблема в длине локализованной строки.

Воспроизводится на iOS, в Opera, Safari и Chrome.

- Устройство: iPhone 5 (Global)
- Версия OS: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)